# How do I format a dart file with Prettier?

Tags: dart, prettier, prettier-vscode

[Screenshot of the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdMET.png)

**My Terminal Output --**

```
    ["ERROR" - 3:30:58 PM] Error loading node module 'c:\Users\WELCOME\OneDrive\Documents\Ecommerce Full App\eshoper-dashboard\html'
    ["ERROR" - 3:30:58 PM] Cannot find module 'c:\Users\WELCOME\OneDrive\Documents\Ecommerce Full App\eshoper-dashboard\html'
    Require stack:
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
   > Error: Cannot find module 'c:\Users\WELCOME\OneDrive\Documents\Ecommerce Full App\eshoper-dashboard\html'
    Require stack:
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
    - c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-fork.js
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:934:15)
        at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:779:27)
        at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12684)
        at Function.n._load (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:103:27815)
        at Function.E._load (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:103:24567)
        at Function.c._load (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:93:59196)
        at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1006:19)
        at v (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:4:698)
        at t.ModuleResolver.loadNodeModule (c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:5166)
        at t.ModuleResolver.<anonymous> (c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:4248)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:2894
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at n (c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:2639)
        at t.ModuleResolver.getPrettierInstance (c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:3403)
        at t.default.<anonymous> (c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:8998)
        at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
        at c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:7201
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at n (c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:6946)
        at handleActiveTextEditorChanged (c:\Users\WELCOME\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-8.0.1\dist\extension.js:1:8664)
        at l.fire (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:57:1835)
        at c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:85:46664
        at l.fire (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:57:1835)
        at E.acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:84:148554)
        at E.$acceptDocumentsAndEditorsDelta (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:84:146684)
        at d._doInvokeHandler (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:88:12815)
        at d._invokeHandler (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:88:12507)
        at d._receiveRequest (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:88:11160)
        at d._receiveOneMessage (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:88:9960)
        at c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:88:8064
        at l.fire (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:57:1835)
        at E.fire (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:65:15634)
        at c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:103:29816
        at l.fire (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:57:1835)
        at E.fire (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:65:15634)
        at t._receiveMessage (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:65:20892)
        at c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:65:17778
        at l.fire (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:57:1835)
        at c.acceptChunk (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:65:12995)
        at c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:65:12343
        at Socket.b (c:\Users\WELCOME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:103:13287)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
        at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
        at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
        at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
        at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
   

>  **["DEBUG" - 3:30:58 PM] Using bundled version of prettier.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Prettier does not support `dart` by default. Prettier supports Javascript based tools and frameworks by default.

To add `dart` support to prettier you would need to write your own plugin, you can read more about that on the [plugin docs](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html)

The Dart SDK provides formatting support through the `format` cli command, this formatting is also available to most IDE's with the appropriate plugins.

Comment: @Ahmed if this answer helped you, consider marking it as the accepted answer. So we can help others with the same question on StackOverflow